Add Noise to Mesh such that vertices are moved
I'm a novice with blender, and I'm trying to use it to make some maps for use with robotics simulation in Gazebo. Currently, I'm trying to use noise from geometry nodes to perturb the positions of an existing map.
But I keep running into this issue where even though the noise is added visually, none of the vertices are actually moved from their original positions, which is what gazebo uses  to build maps.
A picture of the mesh and the nodes setup is shown below! I've tried a few things already such as adding a translation node, or connecting the output of my combine XYZ to position rather than offset with no luck.


Why are you using 2 combine xyz nodes?

Where are you looking to the modified mesh to write "none of the vertices are actually moved from their original positions" ? In Editor Mode ?

I found that the second combine node toned down the effect of the noise block, wasn't able to find a well-working set of settings for the noise that wasn't too extreme, and this worked perfectly.
Yes I am looking in editor mode, and when I export to a .dae file I don't get the vertices from the modified mesh.

Edit Mode shows the mesh before applying modifiers. This is why you do not seen any modification. Try and apply the modifier, before exporting.

That is EXACTLY what I was missing, thanks!
